# Get All Installed Application icons in Android : java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, bitmap, classcastexception, nine-patch

There is a `java.lang.ClassCastException` when I am trying to get a installed applications icon.

Here is my code.

```
public Bitmap getAppIcon(String path) {
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(path, 0);
        pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir = path;
        pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = path;
        Drawable icon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
        Bitmap APKicon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        return APKicon;
    }
```

where, `pm` is

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
```

and the error shown in the `LogCat` is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Check this topic please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623570/how-to-programmatically-re-apply-a-9-patch-image-to-an-imageview

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your Problem is that your Icon is no instance of BitmapDrawable, one can check like that:

```
Bitmap APKicon;
if(icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
  APKicon  = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap();
}
```

in this case your solution would be right, one can just cast it, but if not (and that is your case) one needs to do something like that:

```
else{
     Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),icon.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
     icon.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
     icon.draw(canvas);
     APKicon = bitmap;
}
```

this solution will work in any case

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap getAppIcon(String path) {
    PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(path, 0);
    Drawable icon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    Bitmap APKicon = ((NinePatchDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
    return APKicon;
}
```

You have to cast the icon into `NinePatchDrawable` (line 4).

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

**Problem :**

You are trying to typecast `BitmapDrawable` to `NinePatchDrawable`

**Solution:**

Try this:

```
public Bitmap getAppIcon(String path) {
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(path, 0);
        pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir = path;
        pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = path;
        Drawable icon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
        Bitmap APKicon = ((NinePatchDrawable) icon).getBitmap();  // cast to NinePatchDrawable
        return APKicon;
    }
```

`PackageManager.GetApplicationInfo` returns a `Drawable` object. It might not be a `BitmapDrawable`.

**You can test whether it is a BitmapDrawable with:**

If `pm.GetApplicationIcon(packname)` Is `BitmapDrawable` Then ...

If you want to convert a non-BitmapDrawable to a BitmapDrawable then you need to:

- Create a mutable bitmap.
- Draw the drawable with Canvas.DrawDrawable

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I see the message "The method getBitmap() is undefined for the type NinePatchDrawable"