# Nine Patch work in XML but not in code

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

In my application I have a `9.png`. If I set it in XML via

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

it works great but if I use this code: `bubble.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image)` to set the 9.png programmaticly it does not work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Of course: you are applying a **background**, not a **NinePatchDrawable**... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10639923/2649012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
private Drawable displayNinePatch(Bitmap bitmap, Context context) {
    byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
    if(NinePatch.isNinePatchChunk(chunk)) {
        return new NinePatchDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap, chunk, new Rect(), null);
    } else return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

img_image.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon));