# Ninepatch creation at runtime

Tags: android, networking, bitmap, nine-patch

I want to download a compiled Ninepatch file via network and set it into an ImageView.
I already found the following solutions: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime/5519768?newreg=3132aa315c6c4f9ebb1838e5d794731b), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623570/how-to-programmatically-re-apply-a-9-patch-image-to-an-imageview)

My code is:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

private ImageView _imgView;
private Context _context;

public DownloadImageTask(Context context, ImageView imgView) {
    _context = context;
    _imgView = imgView;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
    Bitmap networkBitmap = null;           
    URL networkUrl = params[0];

    try {
        networkBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(networkUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return networkBitmap;
}

@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    byte[] chunk = result.getNinePatchChunk();

    if (NinePatch.isNinePatchChunk(chunk)) {
        NinePatchDrawable ninePatch = new NinePatchDrawable(_context.getResources(), result, chunk, new Rect(), null);
        _imgView.setImageDrawable(ninePatch);
    }
  }
```

}

The Ninepatch that I load via network is compiled using aapt:

```
aapt.exe c -v -S in -C out
```

The Ninepatch is downloaded properly and onPostExecute() is getting called, I also get the chunck from the Bitmap and I'm able to create a NinePatchDrawable, but after setting it to the ImageView the Bitmap doesn't scale.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Dennis

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the `Bitmap` doesn't scale?

Comment: Log.d the chunk, i bet it has all zeroes

Comment: @XaverKapeller the ImageView's size is fill_parent x 45dp and I want the Ninepatch created from the Bitmap to scale up to this size.

Comment: @pskink the chunk's value is [1, 2, 4, 9, ... ]

Comment: ok then post 9 patch and what you got in the ImageView

Comment: did you try to setBackgroundDrawable for a testing purposes?

Comment: I uploaded two screenshots, one with setImageDrawable(Drawable ...) and another with setBackground(Drawable ...) - the first image is loaded by network, the second is a local ninepatch to test the uncompiled version. The compiled ninepatch is also inside: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/64erngvdxa3w94g/2eXz-a75l-

Comment: the third one, its not 9 patch, is it?

Comment: it is a compiled one, created by the commandline in my first post, so you don't see the ninepatch pixels inside

Comment: and can you add the original 9 patch?

Comment: yep, its also added now

Comment: hmm, i give up since there should be two images with red square...